# Changing color to link when element is highlighted

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make this link highlighter and would like to change the color of the link to black when it’s moused over, and stays like that until hovered to another link. How can I achieve this? (codepen: https://codepen.io/marioecg/pen/ZMKvKd)

This is the HTML:

```
<nav>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#0">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#0">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#0">Help</a></li>    
    <li><a href="#0">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<span class="highlight  appear"></span>
```

And here is the JavaScript:

```
// Select all links
const triggers = document.querySelectorAll('a');

// Select highlight element
const highlight = document.querySelector('.highlight');

// Highlight padding values
const paddingTop =  parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(highlight, null).getPropertyValue('padding-top'));
const paddingLeft = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(highlight, null).getPropertyValue('padding-left'));

// Grab size values of the first link
const initialCoords = triggers[0].getBoundingClientRect();

// Create initial values for highlight making by using the size of the first link
const init = {
  width: initialCoords.width,
  height: initialCoords.height,
  top: initialCoords.top - paddingTop + window.scrollY,
  left: initialCoords.left - paddingLeft + window.scrollX,
}

// Set initial values to highlight element
highlight.style.width = `${init.width}px`;
highlight.style.height = `${init.height}px`;
highlight.style.transform = `translate(${init.left}px, ${init.top}px)`;

// Gets size values of each link and updates position, width and height of highlight element
function highlightLink() {
  const linkCoords = this.getBoundingClientRect();
  const coords = {
    width: linkCoords.width,
    height: linkCoords.height,
    top: linkCoords.top - paddingTop + window.scrollY,
    left: linkCoords.left - paddingLeft + window.scrollX
  }

  highlight.style.width = `${coords.width}px`;
  highlight.style.height = `${coords.height}px`;
  highlight.style.transform = `translate(${coords.left}px, ${coords.top}px)`;
}

// Runs function where each link is hovered
triggers.forEach(a => a.addEventListener('mouseenter', highlightLink));
```

Comment: why you don't use CSS?

Comment: this is exactly the kind of thing that CSS is for. You've made it way over-complicated.

Comment: @AlvaroAlves @ADyson

When a link is hovered the white highlighter comes to the link position making it disappear because its color is white. I wish for the link to stay black until the highlighter moves to another position when a link is hovered. 

I know its possible to change the color with `:hover`, but am I really over complicating things because I wish to style it like this? I want to use black and white colors to give a duo chromatic appeal.

Comment: have you tryed :focus?

Comment: Not yet, but @likle solution worked. Thanks!

Comment: @AlvaroAlves no, wishing to use this style is not over-complicating it, I meant that the huge amount of code above is over-complicating it when you can do it all with a line or two of CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[One way](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yxbjpW) you could achieve that effect is by adding a class to the link once you hover it, and then remove it when you hover another link.

[Another way](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rZmvva) would be to use the CSS property `mix-blend-mode: difference;`:
.
I found that it doesn't look very smooth with this approach without adding a `will-change: opacity;` as well.

Comment: Hey thanks! I get more your first way, but just curious how does the second solution work?

Comment: The mix-blend-mode property allows you to define how the color of an element is mixed with the color behind it. Setting it to difference will make it black on white backgrounds and white on black backgrounds.

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't use CSS?
take a look on this pen:
HTML

```
<nav>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#0">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#0">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#0">Help</a></li>    
    <li><a href="#0">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
a{
  color: blue;
}

a:hover{
  color: red;
}
```

https://codepen.io/alvaro-alves/pen/vzmjym